# Can't send an error body on the servlet output

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection

I have the following code that is supposed to send a message to the client (I'm implementing a low level proxy):

```
//I made an httpurl connection to contact the remote server
httpServletResponse.setStatus(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
InputStream servletStream = getResponseInputStream(httpURLConnection); //I take either the output or error stream by evaluating the return code
IOUtils.copy(servletStream, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());
httpServletResponse.flushBuffer();

private InputStream getResponseInputStream(HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection) throws IOException {
    if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() < 400) {
        return httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
    }else {
        return httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
    }
}
```

Now, if the response from remote server is 200 everything works fine.

If the response is 500 I can't see the body on my postman. Why is that?

Comment: please provide full code base

Comment: added the last method

Comment: If the response is 500 I can't see the body on my postman - what does this mean?

Comment: That the response body appears to be empty, even though I can see it is full by debugging